# I am getting exc_bad_access when loading second chart using charts framework

Tags: ios, swift, charts, exc-bad-access

This is my first app and I am pretty green at this. I am using the charts framework to display two different charts on a tabbed application. When I run my app the first view and chart runs smoothly but when I click on the second tab the view tries to load then I get an exc_bad_access error.

I know that this error generally pertains to a memory issue. So I enabled zombies and ran the analyze tool and still have not been able to come up with anything. I get the error at setChart and right after the setChart function runs.

Here is the code:

```
@IBOutlet weak var yourRankRetailLabel: UILabel!

@IBOutlet weak var barChartView2: BarChartView!


var employee: [String]!
var currentRank = ""


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

        DataService.dataService.CURRENT_USER_REF.observeEventType(FEventType.Value, withBlock: { snapshot in //snap

        let rank = snapshot.value.objectForKey("rankretail") as! String

        self.yourRankRetailLabel.text = "You were ranked \(rank) in service sales last week!"
        self.currentRank = rank
        }, withCancelBlock: { error in
            print(error.description)
    })//snap


    employee = ["1491", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec"]
    let unitsSold = [5.0, 4.0, 6.0, 3.0, 12.0, 16.0, 4.0, 18.0, 2.0, 4.0, 5.0, 4.0]

    setChart(employee, values: unitsSold)




}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.



    }

func setChart(dataPoints: [String], values: [Double]) {
    barChartView2.noDataText = "You need to provide data for the chart."

    var dataEntries: [BarChartDataEntry] = []
    for i in 0..<dataPoints.count {
        let dataEntry = BarChartDataEntry(value: values[i], xIndex: i)
        dataEntries.append(dataEntry)
    }

    let chartDataSet = BarChartDataSet(yVals: dataEntries, label: "Units Sold")
    let chartData = BarChartData(xVals: employee, dataSet: chartDataSet)
    barChartView2.data = chartData
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd guess that this label:

```
@IBOutlet weak var yourRankRetailLabel: UILabel!
```

got destroyed.  That is a `weak` reference, which means that if nothing else refers to that label, e.g. a parent widget, then the memory for the label is freed up, so your variable won't refer to a valid location in memory.

Comment: I doubled checked all my references and everything is still connected. Also  in the code I posted the barChartView2 is a Strong variable, I had changed it out of frustration but have since changed it back to a weak variable